# sql creating functions

Tags: mysql, sql, function, stored-procedures

I'm currently studying SQL and I'm working on this exercise.
Can you please check for me my work and please provide correction?

[image: here's the database diagram]

I have to create a function that will take in as a parameter the department id and then return the department name that goes with the department id. I also have to show this function being used when selecting a data from the employee table.

This is my answer:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE my_dept(IN departmentId INT)
BEGIN
SELECT dept_id FROM DEPARTMENT
WHERE dept_name = departmentId;
END//
DELIMITER;

CALL my_dept(‘departmentName’, @departmentId);
SELECT @departmentId FROM EMPLOYEE;
```

Thanks in advance for your direction and correction.

Comment: Your code makes no sense at all.  That's a hint.  Learn how stored procedures work and how to call them.

Comment: You are passing an integer and searching for names that match that integer.  You need to put some more thought into that one.